# How to show/hide the close button on online excel right task pane using office.js add-in

Tags: javascript, angular, office-js

I am using office.js with Angular 6 to create my add-in. I have some event listeners which is running in the background which requires the right side task to be opened or minimized. I want to restrict the users to close the task pane. Can anyone suggest either how to hide the close button or auto minimize or listening to the close event so that I can show some message to the users not to close the task pane.

Expected result is not to allow to close the right side task pane.

Answer (score 1):

At present there is no Office.js API that can hide the task pane close button, and there isn't any that can minimize the task pane. It is an interesting idea. Please go to [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and suggest it.

UPDATE: The new place to suggest ideas is [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).

Comment: The link suggested by @Rick is no longer working (https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)

Comment: @Stephan I have updated my answer with the new link.